# Render result from promises.all in a view, nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**Fixed: `<%- locals.devices -%>`**

So what I'm trying to achieve, as said in the title, is sending an array of json objects result from promises.

```
const switch_p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            conn.query('SELECT * FROM switch', (err, switch_data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                resolve(switch_data);
            });
        });

const ap_p = new Promise etc..
             ...
             ...
             resolve(ap_data);


const server_p = new Promise etc..
             ...
             ...
             resolve(server_data);


const router_p = new Promise etc..
             ...
             ...
             resolve(router_data);
```

These are the 4 promises from which I want to get the value and render them afterwards.

Promises.all function: - I've tried more cases of rendering the values but without success everytime..
This is the last try:

```
Promise.all([switch_p, ap_p, server_p, router_p]).then(values => {

            const responses = values.map(response => values)
            return Promise.all(responses)
        }).then(responses => {
            console.log(responses);
            data = responses
            console.log(data); // here its shows that data has content
            res.render('admin-panel', {
                layout: 'layoutAdmin',
                locals: {_id: sess_id, uname: sess_uname, rol: sess_rol, devices: data}
            });
        });
```

In view I just try to show the content from devices (<%- devices -%>), which I know it'll be something like this:

```
[ [ [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      ........
```

but it says "devices is not defined".. and I don't know why. 
Also if there is a solution on how to do that without breaking the code in multiple functions that'll be cool.

<<<<<<<<<<<<< Edit 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>

Let's forget about the ap_p promise for now.

This are the promises functions:

```
       const switch_p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            conn.query('SELECT * FROM switch', (err, switch_data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                else resolve(switch_data);
            });
        });

       const server_p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            conn.query('SELECT * FROM server', (err, server_data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                else resolve(server_data);
            });
        });

      const router_p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            conn.query('SELECT * FROM router', (err, router_data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                else resolve(router_data);
            });
        });
```

And the promise all function, although I don't know if I handled the error in a good way..

```
Promise.all([switch_p, server_p, router_p]).then(responses => {
            console.log(responses);
            res.render('admin-panel', {
                'layout': 'layoutAdmin',
                'locals': {'_id': sess_id, 'uname': sess_uname, 'rol': sess_rol, 'devices': responses}
            });

        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                throw (error);
            });
```

console.log(responses) does work fine, and the single error that I get is still "devices is not defined".

Comment: Replace `if (err) throw err;` with `if (err) reject(err);`

Comment: `const responses = values.map(response => values)
            return Promise.all(responses)` doesn't make any sense to me. What where you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: What is `conn.query`? Chances are high that it already returns a promise.

Comment: @Bergi first time I tried to do it like Roamer, I mean rendering the value from promise.all directly, but it didn't work out, so I tried to put render function in a promise (to avoid asynchronous execution). //// conn is my mysql connection, and query is just the function through I get my data from tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the promises are created, throwing does not have the desired effect. `reject()` must be called.

Replace ...

```
`if (err) throw err`;
```

with ...

`if (err) reject(err)`.

In the `Promsie.all()` chain,

- purge the first `.then(...)`
- in the second `.then()`, purge `data = responses;` and work with `responses`
- add a `.catch()` handler.

You should end up with ...

```
const switch_p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM switch', (err, switch_data) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(switch_data);
    });
});

// etc.
```

and ...

```
Promise.all([switch_p, ap_p, server_p, router_p])
.then(responses => {
    console.log(responses);
    res.render('admin-panel', {
        'layout': 'layoutAdmin',
        'locals': { '_id': sess_id, 'uname': sess_uname, 'rol': sess_rol, 'devices': responses }
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error here.
    // Either return a value (to put promise chain back on the success path) ...
    // ... or throw/rethrow error (to continue on the error path)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but still didn't worked out... I edited my original post with the new approache.

Comment: Suggest you run a test to check out Bergi's point about  `conn.query()` already returning a Promise. If so, then modify the three promise creations to read eg `const xxx_p = conn.query('SELECT * FROM xxx');`, leaving out the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work, and from what I know, query function doesn't return a promise. I mean I saw multiple implementations with promises in connection_name.query(). But thanks for the opinions, Roamer & Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out what the problem was. I should've render <%- locals.devices -%>... yes a dumb mistake by me. Thanks you for your implication.

Comment: Although it didn't actually solve the issue, there should be no harm in using my code ... with your ` <%- locals.devices -%>` fix.

Comment: It isn't. Your code it's simpler and works fine, and thanks you for the reject err information. To be honest, your implementation was my first try (except the reject err thing), but because I didn't find the mistake I thought the cause may be asynchronous execution of functions, so I created a promise.

Comment: Maybe you could edit my answer with your ` <%- locals.devices -%>` fix, in case it confuses people in the future.